# How to make username in terminal smaller?

Tags: command-line, bash

When you opens a terminal it displays the username and the machine name. As an example mine shows: `romeo@romeo-Satellite-C660D:~$`. It's really annoying because it's kinda big. Can i make this smaller, like, only show romeo?

I know it sounds stupid, but I'm new with Unix based OSes.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to alter `PS1` variable in your environment. `PS1` is responsible of how fancy your command prompt will look alike, and what information it will contain.

**Permanent change**

Following is the excerpt of default `.bashrc` file in Ubuntu 10.04 LTS:

```
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
```

This makes command prompt look like this: `username@hostname:~/directory$`

If you change this and delete `@\h` part in `PS1`, you will get rid of hostname part in your command prompt:

```
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u:\w\$ '
fi
```

Result: `username:~/directory$`

**Temporary change**

Override `PS1` in your current `bash` session:

```
export PS1="\u:\w\$ "
```

*Resources:*

- [man bash](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)
- [How to: Change / Setup bash custom prompt (PS1)](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html)
- [Color Bash Prompt](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Color_Bash_Prompt)

Answer (score 5):

See `man bash` and look for `PS1`.

To reduce the prompt to the user name, you can add this to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
PS1='\u $'
```

Some "advanced" customizations see e.g. : [Bash Shell PS1: 10 Examples to Make Your Linux Prompt like Angelina Jolie](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/bash-shell-ps1-10-examples-to-make-your-linux-prompt-like-angelina-jolie/)

Answer (score -3):

```
export PS1='\t$'
```

since I prefer displaying as little background info as possible on the terminal I generally customize every session as a `#`, `$`, etc.

Comment: How does this answer the question?